# Dashboard problem in Mobile App

Tags: mobile, dashboard, app, custom-reports

I have a problem with my Dashboards in mobile app.
I have created two Dashboards. I put these Dashboards in a Home Page with conditional visibility based on the country of the running user.
For the users of one country, I see the correct Dashboard (the one for his country) from Desktop but from Mobile App I continue to see the Dashboard of the other country.
I tested anything, but I can't find the solution. Please,someone knows how to fix this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks related to this [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000024FyYQAU). Can you check if the workaround of logging out and logging in again updates the Dashboard on mobile?

Comment: Hello, thank you for sharing. Unfortunately, the problem is a little bit different. It's not regarding the data shown in the Dashboard, but regarding the Dashboard itself. I see - only from Mobile - the Dashboard that I have set for the other country and not the correct one. I have tested logging out and logging in but it doesn't seem to work.